# Hide right icons in Dash to Panel

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, gnome-shell-extension

I was wondering if it's possible to hide the icons in the right (between the headphones and hour):
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME Shell 3.34.3.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 and GNOME Shell 3.34.3